# FormData() form Form Element always empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

I've been trying to upload a File with Ajax but the FormData is always empty.

This is the code i'm using to:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../website/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="providerForm">
        <input id="fileI" class="form-control" name="fileI" type="file" />
        <button id="newProviderButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
            value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var providerId = "";
    function newProvider() {

        var a = $("#providerForm")[0];
        var b = $("#providerForm");
        var c = new FormData($(b)[0]);
        var d = document.getElementById('providerForm');
        var dataT = new FormData(d);
        var params = $('#providerForm').serializeArray();
        c.append("file",$($(a).find("#fileI"))[0]); 
        $.each(params, function(i, val) {
            dataT.append(val.name, val.value);
            console.log(val.name + ": " + val.value);
        });
        $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    beforeSend : function(request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                                "multipart/form-data");
                    },
                    url : "../services/user/profile/upload/image",
                    data : dataT,
                    cache : false,
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                    success : function(msg) {
                        if (msg.message == "OK") {
                            mAlert({
                                container : $("#providerForm"),
                                message : 'Usuario registrado correctamente',
                                type : 'success',
                                okButton : 'OK'
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    statusCode : {
                        401 : function() {
                            window.location.replace("../entrance.jsp");
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#providerForm").on('reset',function(){
            $(this).data('formValidation').resetForm(true);
        });
         $('#providerForm').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',

                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                fields: {}
            })
         .on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
                // Prevent form submission
                e.preventDefault();

                var $form = $(e.target),
                    fv    = $(e.target).data('formValidation');

                // Do whatever you want here ...

                // Then submit the form as usual
                newProvider();
                //fv.defaultSubmit();
            });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

You can see the result here.

[image]

As you can see I tried getting the HTMLElement througt different methods and even appending the element individually the result id FormData = {}

**EDIT:**

I need the FormData encoding in `multipart/form-data` format

Answer (score 1):

The best way to upload files is not with Ajax, but if you want to do that, you can follow the belong tutorial:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

The best way to upload files is the traditional method, making a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` refreshing the website, is very simple but same the best way to do that.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Radames, so what do you think is the best way?

Comment: Sergio, the best way to upload files is the traditional method, making a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" refreshing the website, is very simple but same the best way to do that.

Comment: Ok. I was trying to not refresh the page but I think I will have to. Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion, you can separate in 2 steps your form, the first part you can send all information via ajax, and send to the user to another section particularly to upload the file.

Comment: Nice, but I was trying to do something faster. The app is for a work environment. I'm thinking on call submit method programatically to avoid another click or page.

Comment: I created a form with two upload proccesses one to upload the main data, then another one to upload just the file. Thanks @Radames

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (as tagged), try using [form.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) in place of your $.each dataT append.

Comment: Well I need the FormData in multipart/form-data encoding.

Comment: Good point, have you tried:

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append( 'file', $('#fileI').files[0] );

Comment: I see you use "c.append("file",$($(a).find("#fileI"))[0]); " but isnt the extra $() unnecessary?

Comment: `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append( 'file', $('#fileI').files[0] );` gets right the File but does not append it to formData. 

And yes, the extra $ is unnecessary I just tried all the possibilities. 

I don't know if the problem is with the FormData object or the <input type="file">

Comment: Thats strange, sorry I wasnt any help! though it might be a long shot but the docs say that i takes a 3rd optional parameter used for forms, which is the form file name?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: Thanks anyway @Craig, I'm checking out.